# Get the text from a check box list

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkboxlist

I have a `check box list` in a `winform`.

If the check box list is selected then I want the value to be passed into a string:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To cbxlstPancakes.Items.Count - 1
    If cbxlstPancakes.GetItemChecked(i) Then

        Dim currentPancake As String = cbxlstPancakes.SelectedItem.ToString

    Else
        'do something if they are not checked.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `cbxlstPancakes.Items(i).ToString`

Comment: I tried that already as it returns: System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: You didn't document there was anything else in the list but strings.  You will have to cast it to the object that you are using.

Comment: Sorry for being a dunce but I am only using a string.
The check box list does have a DisplayMember and a ValueMember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I'm confused if you're using strings vs. a bound datasource.  For the datasource, give one of these a try.

If you only care about CHECKED items, it's a little easier:

```
    '=== IF you only care about the checked items (assuming you used a databound control)
    For Each dr As DataRowView In cbxlstPancakes.CheckedItems
        Dim currentPancake As String = dr.Item(0)   '--> TODO:  correct column from your datasource
        MessageBox.Show(currentPancake)
    Next
```

IF you care about both checked AND unchecked items, you should be able to access them this way (should work for EITHER bound or unbound):

```
    '=== IF you care about both checked and unchecked items
    For i As Integer = 0 To cbxlstPancakes.Items.Count - 1
        If cbxlstPancakes.GetItemChecked(i) Then
            MessageBox.Show(cbxlstPancakes.GetItemText(cbxlstPancakes.Items(i)))
        Else
            'Do something if they're not checked
        End If
    Next
```

I'm not sure why the CheckedListBox was implemented a little differently than some other controls (with the .Getxxxxx() methods, etc.).  But this seems to work for me!

Comment: You know user changes their mind and if affects my work pattern.

Thanks this is what I wanted. For future reference, if I wanted to assign an ID to the check boxes. How would I get their value?

Comment: This isn't working with string value. but this worked below> Thanks again

 `For Each dr As String In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems

            Dim currentPancake As String = dr   '--> TODO:  correct column from your datasource
            MessageBox.Show(currentPancake.ToString)`